# Сломался Linux при удалении Python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Вчера хотел удалить Python 3.8 и скачать Python 3.10.4, после удаления питона система резко начала глючить, при включении появляться черный экран и курсор как решить проблему?

Пробовал уже заново устанавливать питон, через комбинацию клавиш открыл проводник, и оттуда открыл терминал, а затем скачал питон, но не помогло, система по прежнему мертва

Ps: дистрибутив Ubuntu, окружение KDE Plasma

Comment: вообще, не рекомендуется удалять питон, поставляемый с дистрибутивом, потому что на нем могут работать с том числе и системные службы. если хотите новый питон, использовать нужно виртуальное окружение. в вашем же случае, боюсь, мало что можно исправить.

Comment: Вся проблема в том что изначально на этой системе не был установлен Python, но после его установки и удаления система умерла

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить. 1. Зачем тебе новый питон? 2. Как ты его ставил\удалял?

Comment: Пип устанавливал модули на питон 3.8 а вскод юзал 3.10.4 и было бы удобней скачать новый питон, sudo apt install Python3.8 - sudo apt remove Python3.8

Comment: `Вся проблема в том что изначально на этой системе не был установлен Python` - это, очевидно, заблуждение.

Comment: не заблуждение, я помню как устанавливал его через apt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На черном экране попробуй нажать alt+ctrl+f4 (иногда это получается сделать через 15 минут после загрузки).

Если не получается так, то перезагрузись. На выборе ОС нажми кнопку E и в строчке `linux .....` допиши `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`. Нажимай F10.

Залогинься и выполни команду:

```
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
```